# Google closure library goog.forwardDeclare namespace javascript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures, require, forward-declaration

I have some problem, and I sure community can help me )))

For Example: I have the next javascript files

```
file1.js

goog.provide('namespace.ModuleName');
goog.require('namespace.ModuleName.Item')

/**
* @param {Object} args
*@constructor
*/

namespace.ModuleName = function(args) {
....
..Initialization..
...
var item = [];
item.push(new namespace.ModuleName.Item(args)) // THIS ERROR
}

/**
* @private
*/
namespace.ModuleName.prototype.MyMethod = function() {
...
...
...
}
```

The next part. I want create new file

```
file2.js

goog.provide('namespace.ModuleName.Item')

/**
* @param {Object} args
*@constructor
*/
namespace.ModuleName.Item = function(args) {

}
```

I have some problem because  "namespace.ModuleName.Item" Doesn't know about namespace.ModuleName. I can fix it. I need write goog.require('namespace.ModuleName') below goog.provide('namespace.ModuleName.Item'). 
But I have again some problem. Google Closure compiler writes "Require LOOP" . I can delete line where "goog.require('namespace.ModuleName.Item')". But these solution is not correct

What's the correct way to name modules

I ask this question on google forum. Guys told me "use goog.forwardDeclare"

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/closure-library-discuss/PptH2fzcs_M

I tried write goog.forwardDeclare('namespace.ModuleName') above\below goog.provide('namespace.ModuleName.Item'). But it it's not worked for me. Can you help me ? Please. Or maybe write some examples. How use goog.forwardDeclare.